# WWW::Mechanize::Firefox click button in <div>

Tags: perl, firefox, selector, mechanize, www-mechanize-firefox

I got a big problem. I have 12  elements with the same class - "comment". In every  is button to click.

I need to know how to select  (eg. 3 of 12) and click button only there.

Is exist any selector or something? Please give me some advice about that.

Answer (score 2):

[$mech->click](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.74/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox.pm#%24mech-%3Eclick%28_%24name_%5b,%24x_,%24y%5d_%29) can take a CSS selector or an XPath query as an argument. If you know that the button you want to click will *always* be the third one, you could use something like the [nth-of-type](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthoftype) CSS selector to pinpoint it.

**EDIT:** An example using XPath based on the OP's comments (I haven't tested this). Use `qq` to allow variable interpolation inside the XPath statement. Note that you have to backslash escape occurrences of `@` so `qq` doesn't interpret them as arrays:

```
my $author = 'xxx';
$mech->click({ xpath => qq(//div[\@class="com" and \@author="$author"]/button) });
```

Comment: yes, i know, but this button can be 3 and 10 seconds later can be 4.
so i need select div with this button :( is any possible method for that? thanks.

Comment: @KamilHajduk What determines which button you need to click?

Comment: it's look like this:
<div class="com" author="xxx">
  ..............
   <button type="submit">
</div>

<div class="com" author="yyyyy">
  ..............
   <button type="submit">
</div>


So it's determines by <DIV> section. You have any ideas?

Comment: or maybe this module support something like separate <DIV> by author name and then click button number 1 (the only one in there)

Comment: @KamilHajduk XPath lets you select elements from the DOM using complex criteria. There's a good intro to XPath [here](http://oreilly.com/perl/excerpts/system-admin-with-perl/ten-minute-xpath-utorial.html). See my edit for an example.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have one more question. I got xpath query like @divs = $mech->xpath('//button[@class="submit"]', single => 1); and in output that give me 12 elements.

Can i determine click in eg. third button?

I mean that i got 12 buttons with the same class and i want to click button number three.

Is it possible?

$mech->click accept xpath but $mech->button_click accept number of button but xpath not :(

Comment: @KamilHajduk Yes, that is possible. Your XPath would look something like `//button[@class="submit"][3]` (note XPath indexes start with 1, not 0). Please read more about XPath, you can do just about anything with it.

Comment: Man you are awesome! I must learn more about this XPath! It's powerfull tools :)

 I got last question.

I got XPath query '//div[@class="comment" and @author="6546678"]/div/div[2]/span[2]/button' and it's working but when i try to do @author="$author_id" - it's not working.

I try to change this in qq## and "" but it's still not working. Is it possible to add string in '' ? When i add author id manually, not in string, it's works fine, but not with string. I would like to know how to do this, becouse this author id will be dynamic.

Comment: @KamilHajduk See edit. If you have additional questions, please open a new question instead of adding comments to this answer. And if my answer solved your problem, you can accept it by clicking the check mark next to it :-)